# Intent that loads another class makes unexpected error

Tags: android, android-intent

In src, I have Announcement.java, MainActivity.java.

 I wanted to call Announcement.java on MainActivity.java after clicking the button.

```
<MainActivity>
Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Announcement.class);
startActivity(intent1);

<Announcement>
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.announcement);
```

However it makes an unexpected stopping error. I've confirmed that when I move

**Intent intent1~Announcement.class);**

right below to public class statement, It got an unexpected after I emulated the application.

I will be really thankful for your help.

Freshman on Android...:( Sorry.

**This is the logcat**

> 08-18 08:42:57.044: D/AndroidRuntime(27901): Shutting down VM
>
> 08-18 08:42:57.044: W/dalvikvm(27901): threadid=1: thread exiting with
>   uncaught exception (group=0x41614ce0)
>
> 08-18 08:42:57.044: E/AndroidRuntime(27901): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> 08-18 08:42:57.044: E/AndroidRuntime(27901): Process:
>   kr.hs.honam.honamhighschool, PID: 27901
>
> 08-18 08:42:57.044: E/AndroidRuntime(27901):
>   android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit
>   activity class
>   {kr.hs.honam.honamhighschool/kr.hs.honam.honamhighschool.Announcement};
>   have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
>
> 08-18 08:42:57.044: E/AndroidRuntime(27901):  at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
>
> 08-18 08:42:57.044: E/AndroidRuntime(27901):  at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
>
> 08-18 08:42:57.044: E/AndroidRuntime(27901):  at
>   android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
>
> 08-18 08:42:57.044: E/AndroidRuntime(27901):  at
>   android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)
>
> 08-18 08:42:57.044: E/AndroidRuntime(27901):  at
>   android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3627)
>
> 08-18 08:42:57.044: E/AndroidRuntime(27901):  at
>   android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3595)
>
> 08-18 08:42:57.044: E/AndroidRuntime(27901):  at
>   kr.hs.honam.honamhighschool.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:41)
>
> 08-18 08:42:57.044: E/AndroidRuntime(27901):  at
>   android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2600)
>
> 08-18 08:42:57.044: E/AndroidRuntime(27901):  at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:1065)
>
> 08-18 08:42:57.044: E/AndroidRuntime(27901):  at
>   com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:741)
>
> 08-18 08:42:57.044: E/AndroidRuntime(27901):  at
>   com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
>
> 08-18 08:42:57.044: E/AndroidRuntime(27901):  at
>   com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:884)
>
> 08-18 08:42:57.044: E/AndroidRuntime(27901):  at
>   com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
>
> 08-18 08:42:57.044: E/AndroidRuntime(27901):  at
>   com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.onItemClick(MenuPopupHelper.java:177)
>
> 08-18 08:42:57.044: E/AndroidRuntime(27901):  at
>   android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
>
> 08-18 08:42:57.044: E/AndroidRuntime(27901):  at
>   android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
>
> 08-18 08:42:57.044: E/AndroidRuntime(27901):  at
>   android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2911)
>
> 08-18 08:42:57.044: E/AndroidRuntime(27901):  at
>   android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3645)
>
> 08-18 08:42:57.044: E/AndroidRuntime(27901):  at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>
> 08-18 08:42:57.044: E/AndroidRuntime(27901):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>
> 08-18 08:42:57.044: E/AndroidRuntime(27901):  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>
> 08-18 08:42:57.044: E/AndroidRuntime(27901):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5139)
>
> 08-18 08:42:57.044: E/AndroidRuntime(27901):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>
> 08-18 08:42:57.044: E/AndroidRuntime(27901):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>
> 08-18 08:42:57.044: E/AndroidRuntime(27901):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
>   08-18 08:42:57.044: E/AndroidRuntime(27901):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
>
> 08-18 08:42:57.044: E/AndroidRuntime(27901):  at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Have you added Announcement.java in your manifest. Can you post your your error

Comment: @Indra I think I could upload it tomorrow.. Could you wait for it?

Comment: @Indra I've attached log cat. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to the manifest your Announcement activity. Check if your type correctlly the name of your package.

Comment: Thanks. Modified on Manifest.